# How to negate countif

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am using countif quite often. However, I was wondering if I want to look for something not like:

`=Countif(A:A;"1")`, which counts all 1 but I want to count in which cell there is NO 1.

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"<>1")
```

For excluding also empty cells use [COUNTIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) (works in Excel 2007 and later):

```
=COUNTIFs(A:A;"<>1";A:A;"<>")
```

for Excel 2003:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")*(A:A<>1))
```